# How to handle Voice message on Microsoft Bot Framework Skype channel using Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype, voice-recording

I am developing a bot using Microsoft bot framework using Node.js. The app is deployed in Skype channel. The user can interact with bot either using text or voice commands. In mobile version of Skype we can send voice message using recording icon available in mobile. Bot emulator automatically convert speech to text. I want the same in Skype channel. When I send instant voice recordings in Skype it respond as **I didn't understand. Please try again.** I dont know how to handle in Skype. I want the voice recordings send by user. So that I can send that voice recordings to Bing Speech api and get the appropriate text for that. Please help me to solve it.
**Note : I dont want to use Skype call . Just normal chat similar to whatsapp the user can send text and instant voice recordings.**

A small update on this. Now I got to know how to find the attachment. using **session.message.attachments[0]** I got the following json:

```
 attachments: 
   [ { contentType: 'audio',
       contentUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/attachments/0-sa-d6-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/views/original',
       thumbnailUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/attachments/0-sa-d6-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/views/thumbnail',
       name: '3-audioMessage.m4a' } ],
```

The audio is stored in .m4a format. But Bing speech supports only .wav format. I need to convert that to .wav format

```
let load = require('audio-loader');
let msg = session.message;
let audiouri =msg.attachments[0].contentUrl+"/"+msg.attachments[0].name;
 load(audiouri).then(function (buffer) {
        console.log("Audio Buffer is  ",buffer); // => <AudioBuffer>
        var wav = toWav(buffer);
        console.log("my wav format audio is " ,wav);
      }).catch(function(error)
      {
        console.log("Catched error is" ,error);
      });
```

Here I got the error as **Source not found**. I check with reading local .m4a file and the same error occurs. But in case of other formats like .mp3 I got the buffer. Only when I try to read .m4a files the error occurs. Help me by giving reference to convert .m4a files to .wav format in node.js

Comment: Muthu, there is a library that converts AudioBuffer files: https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api.

I'm not certain how to use it serverside, but I did find this stack overflow answer that might be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389843/convert-m4a-to-wav

Comment: Thank for your reply JJ_Wailes. I handled the issue by passing token from botbuilder connector and then use web-audio-api and audiobuffer-to-wav node modules to convert it to .wav file. To get token refer https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-ReceiveAttachment/app.js

Comment: How did you get the audio?